# WIX:Getting error while starting the WCF service after installing

Tags: wix

I am trying to create a wix installer to install and start a Windows Service.
I am getting the following error:
 "Service"() could not be installed. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to install system services."

Below is the script i am using:

```
<File Id="filFBC5F84CB0C200C1A2F8FFB335A07753" KeyPath="yes" 
      Source="..\..\TestDotNet\Monarch.Server.WCF\EFI.Monarch.Server\bin\Release  \EFIMonarchServer.exe" />
<ServiceInstall Id="MonarchServerServiceInstaller"  
                Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes"  Name="EFI Monarch Server" 
                DisplayName="EFI Monarch Server"  
                Description="Testing EFI Monarch Server"  
                Start="auto" Account="LocalSystem" 
                ErrorControl="ignore" Interactive="yes" >
</ServiceInstall>  
<ServiceControl Id="StartService" Start="install" 
                Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" 
                Name="DiskManagement" Wait="yes" />
```

Comment: Can you start the service manually, after installation??

Comment: yes i am able to start it manually. Its is only giving this error when i try to start the service after installing it.

Comment: Its working. i had put the wrong name in servicecontrol element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That message is always a red herring.  It basically means you had an error starting the service.   Anytime I put a new service into the install I leave the ServiceControl element out at first and start the service manually.   If it won't start, I ( or the developer ) profile it to find out why.  You could be missing a dependency, a problem with a service account ( not here ), problems connecting to a database or reading an xml file.  The point is there is usually a problem with the service it self.

Once I can start it manually I go back and put the ServiceControl element back in.

Comment: I am able to start it manually. I dont think i am missing any dependency.

Comment: Are any of your dependencies in the GAC?  If so, there's a race problem in windows installer where you can't start a service that depends on a file you just installed to the GAC because MsiPublishAssemblies doesn't call into Fusion until the commit phase which is after the service tries to start.

Comment: For additional profiling, put the servicecontrol element back in and if/when you get the error, try to start it manually at that moment while the install is hung.